# What's a more efficient way to browse module functions, object methods, etc than just help(), or dir()?

Tags: python, sublimetext

As I explore new modules, I find it very inefficient to iteratively check help() and dir(), and that  dir() doesn't even differentiate between classes, methods and class variables. I know that I can check the source code but that's hardly practical. Is there any Sublime plugin that allows you to see these things in a tree like view, with inline help that automatically pulls from help(), and that uses some visual language to differentiate these kinds of things?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the documentation? Python's is excellent, and many popular 3rd-party modules have good docs as well.

Comment: For quick checks, I use just the `dir()` or `?`, and for deep dives I read the source code. Ipyhon shell autocomplete is also useful. While writing code, the python intellisense of VSCode has been very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sublime Text, check out the [`Anaconda`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda) plugin (not related to the Anaconda Python distribution). Make sure you read all the docs and configure it properly, but once it's going the autocomplete and code intelligence features can be really helpful.

I still highly recommend becoming familiar with the Python docs, as there is a lot in there that no IDE feature can replicate.